# How can I authenticate a request using Laravel Passport having the access token in query string instead of in header?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-passport

Authentication works fine using `'middleware' => 'auth:api'` on regular endpoints where the client sends the `Authorization=Bearer <access_token>`.

But now I'd like to handle plain image download requests, without Authorization header, having the access token in the query string like this: `GET /picture/my_picture.png?access_token=1234`.

I tried something like this in my middleware, but I can't seem to add headers to the Request:

```
if ($request->has('access_token')) {
    // something like $request->header->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->get('access_token'));
}

if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
    // throw exception
}
```

Can this be done? Maybe intercept or override something/somewhere else?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had similar issue
In your
App\Http\Kernal.php

register your middleware in
$middleware and
$routeMiddleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\AddHeaderAccessToken::class,

        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
//            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'addAccessToken' => \App\Http\Middleware\AddHeaderAccessToken::class,
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

        'scopes' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckScopes::class,
        'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class
    ];
}
```

Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class AddHeaderAccessToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if ($request->has('access_token')) {
         $request->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $request->get('access_token'));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but it didn't work, the Auth::user() is always null, when I do `die(dd($request->headers)); ` it shows the header of authorization bearer XXXXXX,

Comment: @seddik, for me it's working fine....thanks to user3209130......

seddik, maybe you should share your full code...

Comment: Worked fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: Working fine. Thanks. I needed this.